# Additional Java process slowing down Android Studio and the whole system

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, slowdown

It's been a while that I have noticed that after using Android Studio for a while, another Java process starts, consumes a lot of memory and eventually freeze Android Studio and the whole system becomes unresponsive. If I kill that process, nothing happens, but both system and Android Studio start operating normally.

This is how it looks

[image]

When I hover over the additional java process, I get this info

[image]

Anyone has any idea how to solve this issue? Is this an Android Studio bug after all?